# javers anyDomainObject method gives an exception

Tags: java, spring, jpa, hql, javers

I am stuck for javers **anyDomainObject** method, it gives an exception.

Actually javers gives a proper data if i am used **byInstanceId** method.

for example:

```
Changes changes = javers.findChanges( 
    QueryBuilder.byInstanceId("1", LoyaltyProgramSetting.class)
    .from(date1.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime())
    .to(new Date().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime())
    .withNewObjectChanges(true).build());
```

above method execute successfully but when i am used anyDomainObject Method, for example
**

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 45);
Date date1 = cal1.getTime();

Changes changes1 = javers.findChanges( 
QueryBuilder.anyDomainObject().from(
date1.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime())
.to(new Date().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime())
.withNewObjectChanges(true).build())
```

**
so this above method throws an exception.
exception like:
Throwable java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.getTargetException()

i am also try

`Changes changes = javers.findChanges( QueryBuilder.anyDomainObject().build());`

but same as it is throws an exception

if any help is appreciated,Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your quest. For starters edit your question instead of adding additional information as comments, secondly include the full stacktrace instead of only a vague message.

Comment: Please report an issue if you can come up with a **runnable test case**, see https://github.com/javers/javers/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#guidelines-for-bug-reporting